# Any idea what the purpose of the commented out parts are?

Tags: python, normalization

I recently posted a question asking about normalization and how I would go about it.
I ended up implementing some code someone gave me after a brief explanation of it.
However I edited it a bit to take out parts that I thought seemed unnecessary, and the code still runs well. I was wondering if anyone would be able to give some clarity on why you think that some of the code that I commented out was included. Here it is

```
for filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY_IN):
    # Used to find the min and max of the image file
    # min = sys.maxsize
    # max = -sys.maxsize
    filepath = DIRECTORY_IN + filename

    image = Image.open(filepath)
    new_image = image.resize((224,224))    
    np_image = asarray(new_image)

    # Performing minmax normalization
    # if min > np_image.min():
    min = np_image.min() # Get min
    print(min)
    # if max < np_image.max():
    max = np_image.max() # Get max
    print(max)
    np_image = np_image.astype('float32')
    print('Min: %.3f, Max: %.3f' % (np_image.min(), np_image.max()))
    np_image -= min
    np_image /= (max - min)
    print('Min: %.3f, Max: %.3f' % (np_image.min(), np_image.max()))
    # print(np_image)
    img = Image.fromarray(np_image, 'RGB') # Convert back to an image

    # Save to 'Processed' directory
    filename = filename.split(".")[0] + "_processed.png"
    print(filename)
    img.save(DIRECTORY_OUT + filename)
```

Again, it seems to be running fine for me with the parts I deemed unnecessary commented out, but maybe there is some edge/special case I am missing.

Comment: Well, after you set `min = sys.maxsize`, you don't use `min` again until you give it a new value using `np_image.min` (same goes for `max`). Were you initially doing something else to compute `min` and `max` that required an identity (for example, `min(a, sys.maxsize) == a` for bounded `int` values.

Comment: Also, `min` and `max` are built-in functions, so maybe you don't want to shadow those.